# Why did browsers limit :visited selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I understand the privacy concerns, but in [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector) Mozilla states that they are lying to `querySelector()` and `getComputedStyle()`.

If they are already lying to sites, than why limit `:visited` to just simple colors? Couldn't full styling still be hidden from sites using the same method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Limiting the styles that can be applied to visited links prevents them from affecting the layout of unrelated elements in a way that can be queried by `getComputedStyle()` — something that cannot be spoofed without secretly computing the layout of the entire page as if all links were unvisited, which would be extremely expensive performance-wise. This is in the same vein as things like `:visited + span` no longer being applied (not even the properties still allowed in `:visited`).

Consider this proof-of-concept, in which you can click a link to toggle a class name that simulates its visitedness, and see how toggling between `:link` and `:visited` can affect layout:

```js
var a = document.querySelector('a'),
    p = document.querySelector('p + p');

a.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  a.className = a.className == 'unvisited' ? 'visited' : 'unvisited';
  console.log('a is now ' + a.className + '; top pos of following p is now ' + p.getBoundingClientRect().top);
}, false);
```

```css
a.unvisited {
  font-size: 1em;
}

a.visited {
  font-size: 2em; /* A property not normally allowed on :visited */
}
```

```html
<p><a class="unvisited" href="#">Toggle visitedness</a>
<p>Another paragraph
```

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense for styles that alter positions of other elements. Is there a reason `overline` `line-through` `underline` `shadow` `opacity` and other properties that don't affect other elements are also omitted?

Comment: @DD3R: opacity results in the creation of a stacking context which can affect z-index layout. I don't know why text decorations (text-decoration and text-shadow) are not in the list of allowed properties.